# I am trying to insert records in local dynamodb shell. Unable to put item using AWS CLI command prompt. Below is my put query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name mytable ^ --item '{ "CountryCode": {"S": "US" }, "MyBank": {"S": "HSBC"}}'
```

> Error : Unknown options : {, S:, US, },, MyBank: , {S:, HSBC}}' , CountryCode:

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question so as you describe the context in which you get this error, what is exactly that are you asking and please provide a complete, minimal and verifiable example.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using DynamoDB local or DynamoDB in AWS. The local one is the lightweight dev/test that you can do in a JVM or Docker purely for functional testing.

Comment: I am using local dynamodb and the issue is with syntax for which I am running in Windows cmd. After deleting the space and replacing with back slash able to insert data. Thanks for the suggestions.